# Julian date to Month R

Tags: r

I have a period of time (110 years) that has been divided in pentads (5 days periods), so I have 8030 values. What I would like to do is to assign to each value the correspondent month, e.g. the first value corresponding to the first 5 days of the all period will be assigned to January and so on.

Can the chron package do this?

Many thanks

Comment: Please give an example of your data, and tell us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to retireve the month for a date. Let's use today as an example.

```
(x <- Sys.Date())
```

For most date and time behaviour, the `lubridate` package should be your first port of call.  This has the `month` function that does what you want.

```
library(lubridate)
month(x)
## [1] 2
month(x, label = TRUE)
## [1] Feb
## Levels: Jan < Feb < Mar < Apr < May < Jun < Jul < Aug < Sep < Oct < Nov < Dec
month(x, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)
## [1] February
## 12 Levels: January < February < March < April < May < June < July < ... < December
```

The `chron` package has a `month.day.year` function that retrieves those three components of the date.

```
month.day.year(x)
## $month
## [1] 2
## 
## $day
## [1] 14
## 
## $year
## [1] 2014
```

The `data.table` package also has a `month` function.

```
library(data.table)
month(x)
## [1] 2
```

Comment: In base: `as.POSIXlt(x)$mon + 1`

Comment: @Roland Yes.  Take a look at `body(data.table::month)`.